# Joining two tables on two conditions and if it fails join to row with blank cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join two tables on two conditions. I want that if the second condition doesn't hold but there is a blank cell (not null but blank '') in Table 1 then to join to that row. If the second condition doesn't hold then to return a zero.

Join Table 1 and Table 2 - return Table 2 and column 3 from Table 1.

Table 1

```
(A, 1, 0.25),
(A, 2, 0.50),
(A, 3, 0.25),
(A, , 0.50),
(B, 1, 0.25),
(B, 2, 0.50),
(B, 3, 0.25),
```

Table 2

```
(A, 1),
(A, 2),
(A, 3),
(A, 5),
(B, 1),
(B, 2),
(B, 3),
(B, 5)
```

I want to get a return of

```
(A, 1, 0.25),
(A, 2, 0.50),
(A, 3, 0.25),
(A, 5, 0.50),
(B, 1, 0.25),
(B, 2, 0.50),
(B, 3, 0.25),
(B, 5, 0.00)
```

Comment: how would you know the `''` should join to `A,5,0.50`. What if there was *another* row in table b that didn't have a match in table a. Which would you choose, or both?

Comment: do you want to do LEFT or RiGHT JOIN, then change null to ' ' with COALESCE - is that it?

Comment: Both would join to the blank and output for example (A, 5, 0.5) and (A, 6, 0.5)

Answer (score 4):

You can use COALESCE(arg1, arg2, …) in a subquery to get the decimal number for each record in table 2. COALESCE goes through its arguments in sequence, and returns the first non-null value.

That's exactly what you want to do:
arg1: Look for a match on both conditions.
arg2: Look for a matching letter, but a null int value in table 1.
arg3: If there's no match in arg1 or arg2, return 0

Example:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (letter CHAR(1), num1 INT, num2 NUMERIC(5,2))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (letter CHAR(1), num1 INT)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES 
('A', 1, 0.25),
('A', 2, 0.50),
('A', 3, 0.25),
('A', null, 0.50),
('B', 1, 0.25),
('B', 2, 0.50),
('B', 3, 0.25)

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES 
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('A', 3),
('A', 5),
('B', 1),
('B', 2),
('B', 3),
('B', 5)

SELECT t2.*, 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT TOP 1 num2 FROM @table1 WHERE letter = t2.letter AND num1 = t2.num1), 
        (SELECT TOP 1 num2 FROM @table1 WHERE letter = t2.letter AND num1 IS NULL), 
        0
    ) AS missing_number
FROM @table2 t2
```

Yields:

```
letter  num1    missing_number
A       1       0.25
A       2       0.50
A       3       0.25
A       5       0.50
B       1       0.25
B       2       0.50
B       3       0.25
B       5       0.00
```

Comment: Thanks this helps! I am working with a much larger data set and getting the following error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. I obviously haven't used the code correctly.. and idea on how to get around this?

Comment: Yes - this means one of the subqueries in the COALESCE statement is returning more than 1 matching value. I added TOP 1 to each statement - this will limit the output to 1 row, but you need to make sure it's returning the correct row! So, if there are 2 rows in table 1 where letter = 'A' and num1 is null, which one should be in the output? You'll need to finesse your subqueries a bit, but the my edit should run for you. Hope it puts you on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.col3, 0)
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2;
```

Or, if you want the `''` as a default, use two `left join`s:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.col3, tt1.col3, 0)
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2 left join
     table1 tt1
     on tt1.col1 = t2.col1 and tt1.col2 = '' and t1.col2 is null;
```

Or, use `apply`:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.col3, 0)
from table2 outer apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 in ('', t2.col2)
      order by t1.col2 desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: I have it working now. Thank you this really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this approach, based on TOP 1 WITH TIES ... ORDER BY ... :

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
  table2.char_value, 
  table2.int_value, 
  isnull(table1.numeric_value, 0.0)
FROM 
  (VALUES 
  ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('A', 5), 
  ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('B', 3), ('B', 5)
  ) table2(char_value, int_value)
LEFT JOIN 
  (VALUES 
  ('A', 1, 0.25), ('A', 2, 0.50), ('A', 3, 0.25), ('A', null, 0.50), 
  ('B', 1, 0.25), ('B', 2, 0.50), ('B', 3, 0.25)
  ) table1(char_value, int_value, numeric_value)
ON table2.char_value = table1.char_value
AND CASE 
  WHEN table2.int_value = table1.int_value THEN 1 
  ELSE CASE WHEN table1.int_value IS NULL THEN 1 
  END END = 1 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY table2.char_value, table2.int_value ORDER BY table1.int_value DESC)
```